# Primary Keys and CouchDB

Tags: ruby, couchdb, couchrest

CouchDB's versioning is an absolute boon to the application I'm writing, but each of the objects I want to represent in the database has it's own unique identifier (let's call it `my_id`), so I don't really need the `_id` field.

Is there a way for me to tell CouchDB that I want to make my field the primary hey (not `_id`)?

I'm using ruby's couchrest_model, so I know I can do `Model.find_by_my_id(params[:my_id])` if I've put `view_by :my_id` in my class, but this feels like I'm storing an `_id` for no purpose. Should I care?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

would it not be possible to, when you create the document, provide your own id instead of the default one couchb assigns? I don't know if ruby's couchrest can do it, but it's available in the CouchDB API

See here: http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Document_API#PUT

The document ID is passed into the url.

Comment: I certainly could, but I'm hoping to keep the name `my_id` as it carries meaning in my app.

Comment: you can still keep my_id in the document as well. Just set id and my_id to the same thing when you create the document. It's only a tiny bit of duplication and you will never change the id or my_id anyway, right?

Comment: True! It feels a little wrong to have that kind of duplication, but it'll reduce the data stored by a couple of bytes and won't require a new view. Sounds good to me!

Comment: I agree, duplication will always feel a bit dirty, but your requirement to keep my_id doesn't give you many options. Creating some  sort of alias for id on your ruby document might be possible but seems like an even bigger hack. (when you use my_id, my_id behind the scenes returns the value of id, like a custom get function) (I'm no ruby expert)

Comment: That's certainly possible (it's as simple as `alias :my_id :_id` in the class) but it's more about the semantics of the database. Thanks though :)